# coding for last radio button text input

Tags: javascript, html, text, radio-button, var

I have a list of 5 radio buttons, with the last radio button to select a manual entry text (an "other" option). I can't seem to get the form to work for all 5 possibilities - either it returns the radio value or the written value (currently only the written value and not any of the preset radio values). Can't get it to work for all of 5 possible returns.
Here's the javascript to either select text or clear it when unselected:

```
<script type= "text/javascript" >
    function HandleRadioOtherBox(grp, txt)
       {
        var x, len = grp.length;
        for (x =0; x<len; ++x)
        {
            if (grp[x].checked) break;
        }
        if (x < len && grp[x].value == txt.name)
        {
            txt.disabled = false;
            txt.select();
            txt.focus();
        }
        else
        {
            txt.value = "";
            txt.disabled = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    window.onload = function ()
    {
        var ele = document.forms[0].elements;
        return HandleRadioOtherBox(ele['OPS'], ele['Country']);
    }
</script>
```

And here, the HTML radio button portion:

```
  <tr valign="top">
    <td class="style3">Country: </td>
    <td class="copy">
     <input type="radio" name="OPS" value="United States" checked="checked"
     onclick="return HandleRadioOtherBox(OPS, Country)" /> United States
    <input type="radio" name="OPS" value="Canada"
     onclick="return HandleRadioOtherBox(OPS, Country)" /> Canada
    <input type="radio" name="OPS" value="England"
     onclick="return HandleRadioOtherBox(OPS, Country)" /> England
    <input type="radio" name="OPS" value="Australia"
     onclick="return HandleRadioOtherBox(OPS, Country)" /> Australia <br />
    <input type="radio" name="OPS" value="Country"
     onclick="return HandleRadioOtherBox(OPS, Country)" /> Other Country:
      <input type='text' name="Country" id="Country" maxlength='80' />
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Have spent many, many hours with not much of a hole made in the cement (yet). :-)
Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single function for your form which checks for two events:

- radio button `check`
- text input `blur`

and then gives an appropriate response based on which radio button registered a `check` event or whether the text input registered a `blur` event:

```js
var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
var otherCountryRadio = document.querySelector('.other-country input[type="radio"]');
var otherCountryText = document.querySelector('.other-country input[type="text"]');

function returnValue() {
    if (this === otherCountryRadio) {
        otherCountryText.focus();
    }

    else {
        if (this.value.match(/\w/)) {
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
radioButtons[i].addEventListener('change', returnValue, false);
}

otherCountryText.addEventListener('blur', returnValue, false);
```

```css
div {
margin: 12px;
}

.other-country input[type="text"] {
visibility: hidden;
}

.other-country input:checked + input[type="text"] {
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div class="top-countries">
<label><input type="radio" name="OPS" value="United States" checked="checked" /> United States</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="OPS" value="Canada" /> Canada</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="OPS" value="England" /> England</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="OPS" value="Australia" /> Australia</label>
</div>

<div class="other-country">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="OPS" value="Other" /> Other Country
<input type="text" name="Country" />
</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Rounin!
That works nicely to hide & reveal the "other" option and returns the typed-in value, but does not return the radio option values. If I first enter the other value, it "sticks" if I then go back and choose a radio value.

Comment: Very strange though, as I see that running the code snippet you provided works just as it should using the run code snippet on this page but not when I include the code on the page it's included in. I can't seem to pickup the values for any of the radio buttons when submitting to a php script; only for whatever is typed into the text field. If I return to the page and click on a radio button, it then uses whatever I last typed into the text field when I submit (form method="post" action="mailer.php"). All the other values in the form (alumni address update form) are seen by the PHP script.

Comment: You can include an `<input type="hidden" />` in your form. You can then use the script above to change the value of that hidden input. The value that you post  can be the value of that hidden input.